# Pascal assign variable to record field in RAD Studio XE

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-xe

Can anyone comment on where the problem is here?

Compiler error says: Error: Incompatible types: 'Array' and 'name'
Error on line: Student.s_name:=n;

Code as follows.

```
program datafiles;

Uses WinCRT;

Type
    studentRecord = Record
        s_name: packed array[0..30] of char;
    end;

    name = packed array[0..30] of char;

Var
    Student: StudentRecord;
    n: name;

Begin

    readln(n);
    Student.s_name:=n;

end.
```

Comment: This is a Pascal idiosyncrasy. Try defining a new type `a30 = packet array[0..30] of char;` and use that in place of both array declarations, and it should work.

Comment: BTW, with Delphi, it's a lot simpler to use `string` instead of character arrays.

Comment: @Internal Server Error 'packet' is not a reserved word in this compiler. I already have packed arrays, is that what you meant? This compiler doesn't have string data types, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I meant `packed`, of course.

Comment: I re-read your answer and understand what you meant now. This worked! Not used to this level of strongly typed language. Thank you! Please add this as an answer, and I'll mark as the answer to my question.

Comment: Btw, most of the useful answers about Delphi's compiler tend to be tagged with Delphi and those that do tend not to have thet Pascal tag, so I've added it to this one to make it easier to find.

Comment: Pointless to use packed here. Also rather pointless to use an array. Use a string type.

Comment: Thank you everyone, especially @Ken White and MartynA for the edits. David Heffernan thanks for your input. You may be correct, but, as mentioned, strings are not available to me, per a requirement.

Comment: @Mike what compiler/requirement are you actually working with that forbids you from using strings?

Answer (score 2):

The assignment issue is described in the Delphi language documentation:

[Array Types and Assignments](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Array_Types_and_Assignments)

> **Arrays are assignment-compatible only if they are of the same type.** Because the Delphi language uses name-equivalence for types, the following code will not compile.
>
> ```pascal
> var
>   Int1: array[1..10] of Integer;
>   Int2: array[1..10] of Integer;
>     ...
>   Int1 := Int2;
> ```
>
> To make the assignment work, declare the variables as:
>
> ```pascal
> var
>   Int1, Int2: array[1..10] of Integer;
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```pascal
> type IntArray = array[1..10] of Integer;
> var
>   Int1: IntArray;
>   Int2: IntArray;
> ```